# React, useEffect only when 2 elements of dependency array are updated

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a React table component where both `Column` component and a button component rendered inside a column, triggers some function. Example of the table:

```
    <Table>
      <Column onCellClick={handleCell}>
        <button onClick={handleButton} />
      </Column>
    </Table>
```

Those 2 handle functions are called at the same click, and they trigger some `useStates`:

```
    const [cell, setCell] = useState(false);
    const [buttonValue, setButtonValue] = useState(false);

    const handleCell = (value) => setCell(value)
    const handleButton = (value) => setButtonValue(value)
```

SO I have a `useEffect` that must trigger some code ONLY when both `cell` and `buttonValue` are updates. Currently I have something like:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (cell && buttonValue) {
        // some code
        setAnotherState(etc)
      }
    }, [cell, buttonValue]);
```

My problem is if I click very quickly or in random scenarios, the `setAnotherState` is called before the `buttonValue` or `cell` are actually updated. With that `if` inside the useEffect, it will work correctly only the very first time that I actually update both values, because they both are initialized as `false`, but then, with many clicks, there are some outdated set states.

Any hint? how could I ensure that both states actually update before executing the code inside the `if`?

I can't remove any of that 2 onClick or onCellClick, they both have different and specific values for their components, so I need them both.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea using `useRef` to store the collective state as an integer value you can test against.

Cell adds 2 to the state (first taking a modulus of 2 to remove existing 2 values), Button adds 1 (first doing a bit-shift and x2 to eliminate the first bit). When the stateRef is 3, the effect knows both have been changed, sets the other state, and resets the stateRef to 0.

```
    const [cell, setCell] = useState(false);
    const [buttonValue, setButtonValue] = useState(false);
    const stateRef = useRef(0);

    const handleCell = (value) => {
      setCell(value);
      stateRef.current = stateRef.current % 2 + 2;
    };
    const handleButton = (value) => {
      setButtonValue(value);
      stateRef.current = (stateRef.current >> 1) * 2 + 1;
    };
```

Then

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (stateRef.current == 3) {
        // some code
        setAnotherState(etc)
        stateRef.current = 0;
      }
    }, [stateRef.current]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
const [cell, setCell] = useState(null);
// it stores the updated status for cell
const [cellStatus, setCellStatus] = useState(false);
const [buttonValue, setButtonValue] = useState(null);
// it stores the updated status for buttonValue
const [buttonValueStatus, setButtonValueStatus] = useState(false);

const handleCell = (value) => {
  setCell(value)
  setCellStatus(true) // it carried a updated event
}
const handleButton = (value) => {
  setButtonValue(value)
  setButtonValueStatus(true)  // it carried a updated event
}

useEffect(() => {
  // !!(null) === false
  if (!!cellStatus && !!buttonValueStatus) {
    // some code
    setAnotherState(etc)
    // here you reset their status since they were already updated and used
    // now they are not new values but old ones
    setCellStatus(false) 
    setButtonValueStatus(false)
  }
}, [cell, buttonValue]);
```

Thus, the basic idea is to keep track of the values in one variable and the update status in another one.